# Code disappeared after Deploying google cloud function second generation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The source code is disappeared after I've deployed the google cloud function second generation.
I am getting the error:

```
Archive not found in the storage location
```

I can download the zip file with the source code but I cannot use the embedded editor.
What is going on?
The error appear after a deploy in europe-west3, if I deploy it on other location it works.

Comment: Are there any instances that you may have deleted or renamed the GCS bucket that is associated with your Google Cloud Functions?

Comment: No, after a code update and deployment, the code disappeared.

Comment: So what was the problem, can be an external attack? That function generate a file publicly accessible.

Comment: It happens with google cloud function second generation.

Comment: You can check this [public documentation](https://issuetracker.google.com/285748608) regarding with your issue. It stated there a workaround to unblock the editing. Also, there is a button to vote if you are impacted with these cases.

If the workaround didn't work, you can file a bug in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)